# Verify if a user don't have any role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, roles

My question is:
How I can check if a user don't have any role in a guild then continue the code ? (Only @everyone)

The code should run even if a user don't have any role on a guild
It works good when the user have the role... but when the user don't have the role (@everyone doesnt works)

Here's the code for what I've tried so far:

```js
if(message.member._roles == []){
//
adminpermite = false;
}else{
if(message.guild.roles.cache.get(message.member._roles[message.member._roles.length - 1]).rawPosition >= message.guild.roles.cache.get(jsonsv['staffBOT']).rawPosition) adminpermite = true
else adminpermite = false;
};

if(adminpermite){
/* execute code if true  */
}else{
/* execute code if false */
}
```

PS: `jsonsv['staffBOT']` in the configuration is the same id as guild id (something like 000000000000000000)

Any help, please ?

Comment: Instead of `message.member._roles == []` try `!message.member._roles.length`

Comment: What's the purpose of the first check (`if`) . Do you try check the `type` or `length`.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin I'll try and write this on my book! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.member._roles == []` will always return false, so instead try checking the array length `!message.member._roles.length` or `message.member._roles.length === 0`

```
if (!message.member._roles.length) {
  adminpermite = false;
} else {
  if (
    message.guild.roles.cache.get(
      message.member._roles[message.member._roles.length - 1]
    ).rawPosition >=
    message.guild.roles.cache.get(jsonsv["staffBOT"]).rawPosition
  ) {
    adminpermite = true;
  } else {
    adminpermite = false;
  }
}

if (adminpermite) {
  /* execute code if true  */
} else {
  /* execute code if false */
}
```

Comment: thank you so much ! that works !
I'll write this on my book for future !